# Modify the User's DB via code in users_controller.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two users, let's call them UserA and UserB. UserA sends friend request to UserB. This results in creation of a new attribute called as 'Friendtokens' in the UserB's database. The database used is MongoDB.

`Friendtokens: {"919839398393"=>{"atoken"=>"f704e803061e594150b09ad8acabfc6105ac85ab", "confirmed"=>true}}`

Now, when UserA, decides to delete UserB, I need to modify Friendtokens of UserB's DB and delete the UserA's  mobile no. from it.

Any guidance of how could I achieve this by writing a simple code in users_controller.rb would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What type of database do you have?  It's unclear / too broad to answer without this information.

Comment: @La-comadreja: The database is MongoDB.

Comment: Could you post the code of the models in question ? class User, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You are providing little info. Here's a modelisation I can suggest :

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :friend_tokens
  field :phone_number

class FriendToken
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"
  field :confirmed, type: Boolean

  def phone_number
    confirmed ? friend.phone_number : "Friend not confirmed, not showing user phone number !"
  end
```

users_controller.rb

```
def create_friend_request
  @user.friend_tokens << FriendToken.create(friend_request_params)
end

def confirm_friend_request
  token = @userA.friend_tokens.select{|t| t.friend == @userB}.first
  if token
    token.confirmed = true
    token.save
  else
    # Error message
  end
end

def delete_friend
  friend_for_A = @userA.friend_tokens.select{|t| t.friend == @userB}.first
  # Check it has been found
  if friend_for_A
    # Delete friend token for A
    friend_for_A.delete
    # Switch to unconfirmed for user B (we can also assume the token exists)
    friend_for_B = @userB.friend_tokens.select{|t| t.friend == @UserA}.first
    friend_for_B.confirmed = false
    friend_for_B.save
  else
    # Error messages
  end
end
```